# What is the right way to extract values using regex

Tags: php, preg-match

PS: I can't use  DOM etc for this code as Xpath is not working for the html code, which contains huge number of errors from a poorly managed site. This will be easiest way for me.

I've the following html snippet from an erroneous html code:

```
<td width="11%">Train Number</Td>
<td width="16%">Train Name</td>
<td width="18%">Boarding Date <br>(DD-MM-YYYY)</td>

<td width="7%">From</Td>
<td width="7%">To</Td>
<td width="14%">Reserved Upto</Td>
<td width="21%">Boarding Point</Td>
<td width="6%">Class</Td>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD class="table_border_both">*12018</TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">DEHRADUN SHTBDI</TD>
<TD class="table_border_both"> 9- 9-2012</TD>

<TD class="table_border_both">DDN </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">RK  </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">RK  </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">DDN </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both"> CC</TD>
```

I want to grab the values in the last 8 TD's using regular expression. So if I place it within heredoc it does not match. 
How should I place within heredoc so that this pattern( as is) matches?

I'm trying to do like this:

```
 $trainpattern = <<<EOT
<td width="11%">Train Number</Td>
<td width="16%">Train Name</td>
<td width="18%">Boarding Date <br>[(]DD-MM-YYYY[)]</td>

<td width="7%">From</Td>
<td width="7%">To</Td>
<td width="14%">Reserved Upto</Td>
<td width="21%">Boarding Point</Td>
<td width="6%">Class</Td>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD class="table_border_both">[*]12018</TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">DEHRADUN SHTBDI</TD>
<TD class="table_border_both"> 9- 9-2012</TD>

<TD class="table_border_both">DDN </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">RK  </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">RK  </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">DDN </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both"> CC</TD>
EOT;


$ret = preg_match("#$trainpattern#s",$filetext,$matches);
```

Also when I took only first two lines and joined them with \s+ into single line then it is matching but I'm looking for the way to match the lines without joining them at all. May be in that case I'd need to replace \n\r's to \s*'s.

Comment: If the file is this structured, I'd read the last 8 lines one at a time, and then use regex to pull out the values - makes the regex much simpler, and you're working with a smaller, less variable string, which makes the regex parsing a little more reliable.

Comment: In the large html file, locating this snippet is itself the most difficult task.

Comment: @user774250: Use a DOM parser. xPath is not a requirement for PHP's [**DOM**](http://php.net/dom)

Comment: I ran this after the pattern then it's working: $trainpattern = preg_replace('/[\r\n \t]+/s','\\s+', $trainpattern); -- I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) ? If you ever used jQuery, this will not be a problem.

Example :

```
require 'phpQuery.php';
phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($trainpattern);
foreach (pq('td')->slice(-8) as $v) {
    $v = pq($v);
    var_dump((string)$v);
    var_dump((string)$v->attr('class'));
    # etc...
}
```

Output :

```
string(43) "[*]12018"
string(50) "DEHRADUN SHTBDI"
string(45) " 9- 9-2012"
string(39) "DDN "
string(39) "RK  "
string(39) "RK  "
string(39) "DDN "
string(38) " CC"
```

Answer (score 2):

To pull out values, you could use something like that :

```
<?php

// Note: I add <TR></TR> to match

$trainpattern = <<< EOT
<TR>
<td width="11%">Train Number</Td>
<td width="16%">Train Name</td>
<td width="18%">Boarding Date <br>(DD-MM-YYYY)</td>

<td width="7%">From</Td>
<td width="7%">To</Td>
<td width="14%">Reserved Upto</Td>
<td width="21%">Boarding Point</Td>
<td width="6%">Class</Td>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD class="table_border_both">[*]12018</TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">DEHRADUN SHTBDI</TD>
<TD class="table_border_both"> 9- 9-2012</TD>

<TD class="table_border_both">DDN </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">RK  </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">RK  </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both">DDN </TD>
<TD class="table_border_both"> CC</TD>
</TR>
EOT;

// $trs will contains each TRs
$trs=array();
preg_match_all("|<tr>(.+)</tr>|Uis", $trainpattern, $trs);

// $keys will contains TD's value of first TR
preg_match_all("|<td.*>(.+)</td>|Uis", $trs[1][0], $keys);

// $values will contains TD's value of second TR
preg_match_all("|<td.*>(.+)</td>|Uis", $trs[1][1], $values);

// We join keys and values 
$results = array();
foreach ($keys[1] as $index => $key) {
    if (isset($values[1][$index])) {
       $results[$key] = $values[1][$index];
    }
}

var_dump($results);
```

This will show you :

```
array(8) {
  ["Train Number"]=>
  string(8) "[*]12018"
  ["Train Name"]=>
  string(15) "DEHRADUN SHTBDI"
  ["Boarding Date <br>(DD-MM-YYYY)"]=>
  string(10) " 9- 9-2012"
  ["From"]=>
  string(4) "DDN "
  ["To"]=>
  string(4) "RK  "
  ["Reserved Upto"]=>
  string(4) "RK  "
  ["Boarding Point"]=>
  string(4) "DDN "
  ["Class"]=>
  string(3) " CC"
}
```